# Confusion about calling CPU-bound methods synchronously from an async method

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, async-await, task-parallel-library

I'm getting my feet wet with .NET 4.5's async/await construct. I'm working on a RESTful Web API solution. I'm trying to figure out what to do with CPU-bound operation - 1) call it synchronously from the current thread, or 2) use `Task.Run()`?

Let's use the example from this [page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx):

```
async Task<int> AccessTheWebAsync()
{ 
    // You need to add a reference to System.Net.Http to declare client.
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    // GetStringAsync returns a Task<string>. That means that when you await the 
    // task you'll get a string (urlContents).
    Task<string> getStringTask = client.GetStringAsync("http://msdn.microsoft.com");

    // You can do work here that doesn't rely on the string from GetStringAsync.
    DoCPUBoundWork();

    // The await operator suspends AccessTheWebAsync. 
    //  - AccessTheWebAsync can't continue until getStringTask is complete. 
    //  - Meanwhile, control returns to the caller of AccessTheWebAsync. 
    //  - Control resumes here when getStringTask is complete.  
    //  - The await operator then retrieves the string result from getStringTask. 
    string urlContents = await getStringTask;

    // The return statement specifies an integer result. 
    // Any methods that are awaiting AccessTheWebAsync retrieve the length value. 
    return urlContents.Length;
}
```

Here, let's suppose `DoCPUBoundWork()` is strictly CPU-bound and involves no IO of any kind.

Is it the best practice to call it from the current thread as shown?

Or is it better to have the following?

```
await Task.Run(() => DoCPUBoundWork()).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

I've read up on some of Mr. Cleary's posts, and am getting some mixed suggestions. In this [post](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802603.aspx), he suggests that it's better to call the CPU-bound stuff synchronously to avoid the unnecessary overhead of `async/await/Task.Run()`. However, in this [post](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-using.html), he suggests to use `Task.Run()` for CPU-bound operations without mentioning any exception cases. I'm sure I'm missing something obvious. Hoping to get some clarification on this.

Comment: How long your DoIndependentWork runs for typically?

Comment: Let's suppose it takes long enough to cause problems under high load...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is it the best practice to call it from the current thread as shown?

If your current thread is free while the async operating is on going, why use a different thread? What would make *that* thread better than the one you're already using?

Question comes to mind concerning what `DoIndependentWork` is actually doing. If it's vital that it completes before the HTTP request finishes, I would invoke it synchronously. If the work isn't vital to complete before the HTTP request completes, than I would look for an entirely different solution. Using `Task.Run` is dangerous in ASP.NET.

Remember that continuations in ASP.NET run on arbitrary thread pool threads.

Comment: So... when does it make sense to offload it to another thread using Task.Run()? (I'm confused why Stephen Cleary suggests to use Task.Run() for CPU-bound stuff in his blog)

Comment: what about ui-bound *threads* in wpf? firing of an extra task to avoid blocking of the gui would be feasible...

Comment: @Andreas You're right, in case this was WPF I would advise differently. But this is ASP.NET, which is different.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov just despairingly searching for a reason to fire off another task :)

Comment: Regarding the additional comment in your answer: in my case, DoIndependentWork() could be the deserialization of some data (it's not exactly "independent". It has to be done before the request completes. Now I realize that I should have not used this example because the name of the method doesn't help my cause. I'm going to edit my question.

Comment: @Zoomzoom In ASP.NET, you shouldn't even use `Task.Run`. It doesn't register work, and IIS may recycle your app while it's executing. Using `Task.Run` in UI based applications makes more sense and i'm assuming that's what Stephan was referring to.

Comment: I should have read the comments under his blog post. Someone had already asked this same question and Stephen did say something in agreement with you.